# Finding the number of solutions to a product of two sums

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**
Find the number of positive integer solutions to the equation:
$$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4) = 77$$

**Attempted solution:**
The divisors of 77 are 1, 7, 11, and 77. Since we seek *positive* integer solutions we may discard 1 and 77. So the left parenthesis must equal 7 and the right parenthesis must equal 11, or vice versa, with the additional constraint that all integers must be positive.

So, we have either
$$
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2+x_3 &= 7 - 3 = 4 \\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 &= 11 - 4 = 7
\end{align}
$$
or
$$
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2+x_3 &= 11 - 3 = 8 \\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 &= 7 - 4 = 3
\end{align}
$$
Where we now allowing each term to be zero. In the first case there are ${6\choose 2}{10\choose 3}$ ways of doing this, and in the second ${10\choose 2}{6\choose 3}$ ways. So in total there are ${6\choose 2}{10\choose 3} + {10\choose 2}{6\choose 3}$ solutions.

**Problem:** The answer in the book is ${9\choose 2}{14 \choose 3} + {13\choose 2}{10\choose 3}$, but I don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: Your solution looks correct except for those $-4$ and $-3$ terms which I don't see where they came from. That other answer would be the number of *non-negative* integer solutions to the two systems.

Comment: @bjorn93 each $x_i$ and $y_i$ are positive, so they each contribute at least $1$ to each sum. There are $3$ $x_i$ and $4$ $y_i$.

Comment: @Hendrix Yes, but in the first system $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$, not $=4$, so the way it's written is a bit unclear.

Comment: @bjorn93 Ah, now I see your issue. Yes, it is unclear to reuse $x$ and $y$ in the second system without small clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$ case

You say there are $6 \choose 2$ options to do this with positive integers, and the book says $9 \choose 2$.  Who is right?

Since they have to be positive numbers, we can set this up as a stars and bars problem, where you have to divide $7$ stars:

$*******$

using $2$ bars to get $3$ non-empty groups of stars. So, the bars cannot be at either end of the stars, and they can also not occupy the same spot between any two stars. So, the bars need to occupy $2$ out of the $6$ in-between spots, and so you get $6 \choose 2$ options for that.  So yes, *you* are right.

The book no doubt considered the case where the numbers are *non-negative integers*, in which case you add two bars to the $7$ stars in any position, and thus you get a string of $9$ objects with $2$ bars occupying $2$ of those $9$ positions, giving you $9 \choose 2$ possibilities.